# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, syntax-error, keyword-argument, positional-argument

I have a python 3 function which is defined like below:

```
def hidden_markov_model(distribution, K=3, N=100, *args):
```

when i call the function, i get this error:

```
Q_hmm = hidden_markov_model(Gaussian, K=K, N=N, 
                            mu, K*[std**(-2)*np.identity(2)],
                            )

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Get rid of `K=` and `N=` in the function call. These are the keyword arguments python is complaining about.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Understand. I should call it like this:

```
 Q_hmm = hidden_markov_model(Gaussian, K, N, 
                            mu, K*[std**(-2)*np.identity(2)],
                            )
```